# Texture re-mapping a complex model generated with photoscan 3D

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, photogrammetry

I need to model 3 complex objects.
They are made of chocolate.
1 Little bear
2 Dog
3 Santa hugging snowman

Final use is for a 3d viewer online.
So topology is not priority.

I run the way of 3D scanning and then importing as OBJ file.

Now I have some problems.

- The model is full of triangles (it could be ok)
- The mesh don't has detail
- Details are generated by texture map
- Texture map is a mess (see image)

I don't need a super accurate model, I could be happy also with the photoscanned material, but the texture is really mess, there are imperfections due to scratches, drops of condensation.

So I want to fix the texture map in photoshop, but it's really bad unwrapping.

What I can do?
Unwrap, bake texture and fix texture in photoshop and reapply?
But It's hard to unwrap with all these triangles.

[image: WIREFRAME]

[image: SOLID]

[image: MATERIAL_VIEW]

[image: REFERENCE]

[image: TEXTURE_MAP]

Comment: You can rebake the texture to a new, more clean UV map to have a more "readable" image texture if you want. If the mesh is too meesy to unwrap for you, you can always consider retopo. Tools like quad remesher can do that automatically if you don't want to do it manually.